# How to apply sklearn's EllipticEnvelope to find out top outliers in the given dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers

I am using sklearn's `EllipticEnvelope` to find outliers in dataset. But I am not sure about how to model my problem? Should I just use all the data (without dividing into training and test sets) and apply `fit`? Also how would I obtain the outlyingness of each datapoint? Should I use `predict` on the same dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way to do this is:

1. Divide data into `normal` and `outliers`.
2. Take large sample from `normal` data as `normal_train` for fitting the novelty detection model.
3. Create a test set with a sample from `normal` that is not used in training (say `normal_test`) and a sample from `outlier` (say `outlier_test`) in a way such that the distribution of the `test` data (`normal_test` + `outlier_test`) retains population distribution.
4. Predict on this `test` data to get usual metrics (`accuracy`, `sensitivity`, `positive-predictive-value`, etc.)

*Wow. I have come a long way!*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, call `Fit` to train it using all your data. Then you can either call `Predict` using all your data, which returns 1 for inliers and -1 for an outlier, or build up a matrix of all points (to encompass all your data points) and call `Predict` on each point, then plot the results, which would give you a nice image of the ellipse.

Here's a [full example](https://scikit-learn.org/0.17/auto_examples/covariance/plot_outlier_detection.html) with comparison to other methods.